# Rust using higher order function on a struct embedded in another struct

Tags: struct, rust, fold

I am writing some simulations to look at the hiring practices in university departments. So I have different groups of professors in a department which I contain in a `struct.` There are multiple groups in the department. So each professor group is made up of members at different Professor Ranks: Full, Associate, or Assistant professors.

To group all of the professors at the same rank, I created another `struct` called `DepartmentLevels` which contains a reference to a vector of the `ProfessorGroups` struct. Now each `ProfessorGroup` has an attribute `current_number` which indicates the number of professors in that group.

So I am trying to write a method on the `DepartmentLevels` struct that sums up the professor counts for each group in the vector--and hence the total number of professors at that level. Since the vector is an iterator, I thought I could use a higher order function. The problems is trying to get the higher order function to work properly to access the nested `struct.` I was hoping someone might be able to point the way.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct ProfessorGroup<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    gender: Gender,
    level: ProfessorRank,
    attrition_rate:f64,
    promotion_rate:f64,
    hiring_rate:f64,
    current_number:i32,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct DepartmentLevels<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    professors: &'a Vec<ProfessorGroup<'a>>,
    number_of_vacancies: i32,
    number_of_promotions: i32,
    number_of_hires: i32,

impl<'a> DepartmentLevels<'a> {
    pub fn get_professor_count(&mut self) -> i32 { //PROBLEM BELOW
        let result = self.professors.iter().fold(0,|sum, self.professors.current_number| sum + self.professors.current_number);
        result
    }
}
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
error: expected one of `,`, `::`, or `:`, found `.`
  --> src/DepartmentLevels/DepartmentLevels.rs:18:55
   |
18 |         let result = self.professors.iter().fold(0,|sum, self.professors.current_number| sum + self.professors.current_number);
   |                                                       ^ expected one of `,`, `::`, or `:` here

error[E0424]: expected unit struct/variant or constant, found closure capture `self`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols between the vertical bars in a closure are parameter names, not arbitrary expressions.

`fold` passes two arguments to the closure: the current accumulator and an item emitted by the iterator (which in this case is a reference to an item in the vector). A good name for the second argument here would be `professor_group`. We can then use the name `professor_group` to perform any operation on the current `ProfessorGroup`, e.g. access one of its fields.

```
pub fn get_professor_count(&mut self) -> i32 {
    self.professors.iter().fold(0, |sum, professor_group| sum + professor_group.current_number)
}
```

Comment: Oh okay. I will give that a shot. Thanks for the direction on this.